# window.scrollTo(0, 0) having no effect in Angular app

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am building a simple personal website with Angular, and when I switch pages, my scrolled position says the same(or jumps to the bottom of the new page if it is shorter).  I tried using `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`, on both `ngInit` and the constructor.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

so when you change to a component from another component the new component appears like if you have been scrolled to the bottom?
can you repoduce it in stackblitz to check it?
or are you rendering some list or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right.  I'm not rendering a list.

Comment: if you dont resolve it already try to reproduce it in stackblitz and post the url to check the code online

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [scrollPositionRestoration](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration)
This is basically an option in angular routing. We can use to configure the
router to remember and restore scroll position as the user navigates around application.

```
const routes: Routes = [ ... ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The values can be **top** (go to top on every navigation change) or **enabled** (restores the last position) or **disabled** which means scroll position is maintained on navigation.

Comment: I tried a bunch of the different options for this, but none of them made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I used to solve this problem with router-outlet activate  event

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>

onActivate(event: any) {
  // you can do other stuff here
  window.scroll(0, 0);
}
```